# DrupalGap response is HTML instead of JSON

Tags: views, 7, mobile-tools

I want to build a restful service to communicate with my Android app.

- System: Drupal Commons with Drupal 6
- Module for restful service: [DrupalGap](http://drupalgap.org)
- Test tool: Poster plugin for Firefox

I do everything like in the tutorial from [Tyler](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile), but I got my login screen as HTML, instead of correct login; I can't get the system connect states as anonymous user. If I am already logged in so the login functionality says "you alread logged in" and the system connect state shows correct data.
The Views module has a setting to enable "Views API Mode" to wrap JSON in HTML, but this setting is disabled and so this can't be problem.

Does anybody know a solution for my problem?

If I follow the installation instructions for DrupalGap on a fresh Drupal 6 site, everything works out of the box. I can also access the DrupalGap demo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution for our problem.
Under admin -> settings -> commons uncheck the box "Force users to login".
Now it is possible to get json responses from connect and login actions.